# ¿Es posible quitar el encabezado y pie de pagina al imprimir con los navegadores?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Quisiera saber si es posible que se desactiven automaticamente los encabezados y pie de pagina que genera google chrome o firefox.

Fecha, titulo de la pagina, Direccion URL y numero de paginas.

Existe una forma manual, dandole otras opciones y quitando el check de dicha opcion.

pero quisiera saber si es posible con javascript u otro elementos, pero que la persona al pulsar imprimir en mi pagina web pueda tener su archivo sin esos agregados

uso: window.print();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El estándar de CSS te habilita formatos avanzados. Existe la directiva @page en CSS que te permite dar formato a media pages (como el papel). Aquí hay documentación interesante al respecto http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/page.html.

bastaría con incluir esto en tú CSS para remover el encabezado y el pie de página.

```
@page 
    {
        size:  auto;   /* auto es el valor inicial */
        margin: 0mm;  /* afecta el margen en la configuración de impresión */
    }
```